# In Islam when does a new day start?

Tags: time, lunar-calendar

When we start a new day, we usually start it at 12am.

But what about in Islam? Does a new day start at Maghrib time or Fajr time?

Someone told me it is either one of those times.

Is this true? What is a new day or next day considered in Islam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Islam, a new calendar day starts with Magrib.

Comment: I am afraid I'll have to reject your edit to my answer since shirk is actually also forgiven on sincere repentance in Islam but blasphemy is never forgiven, when the conquest of Makkah happened Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) said "Forgive everyone If they seek forgiveness except the blasphemist (i.e. the people that knowingly disrespect Allah, his Prophets (Peace Be Upon Them All) and the Prophet's companions and the angels) Even If they plead in repentance while sticking themselves to the cover of the ka'ba.